# Google Map v2 Add an animation when marker appear

Tags: android, android-animation, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

in iOS, Google Map allow to provide an animation when Marker pop on map.

I'am looking to do the same on Android. So there is nothing to do it or someone know a workaround?

Comment: Are you using Custom maps activity for your app ?

Comment: I'am using a mapFragment that i push on a fragment in a custom activity. But i'am not sure if it's what you ask.

Comment: Isn't the marker always present on the screen but the map loads and then you can perform your animation on onMapClick ?

Comment: No, i got an API call that return me data and i put marker with that data on my map. And this is when I put it on the map that I want to animate it.

Comment: Did you try my solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can animate marker with general Android approach: [Animations and Transitions](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html). Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40347772/6950238) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40155459/6950238) as examples:

> ```
> private static void animateMarker(final Marker marker, final int current, final LatLng[] line) {
>     if (line == null || line.length == 0 || current >= line.length) {
>         return;
>     }
>
>     ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(marker, property, typeEvaluator, line[current]);
>     animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
>
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
>             animateMarker(marker, current + 1, line);
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
>
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
>
>         }
>     });
>
>     animator.setDuration(DURATION);
>     animator.start();
> }
> ```

or use libraries, like [that](https://github.com/aarsy/GoogleMapsAnimations).

Answer (score 0):

As per your `response` from the server, you receive/extract the `latitude` and `longitude`.

```
 //call this method for adding marker with lat and long

    public void addmarker(){
     LatLng marker = new LatLng(double lat, double long);
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker)
                    .title("My title"));
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(marker));
// now the marker is set
// add a delay of 100-200 ms and start you animation (delay for failsafe)
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to move the camera to the new marker i want to make an animation on markers when they all appear (For exemple it can be a fade) To avoid the default instant pop

Comment: @TomJouin How the user will see the animation if you do not move the camera towards the position where you have put the marker.

Comment: The map is zoom over Paris, and have many marker on map. When i select a particular date that show every marker at this date on map. I know how to move camera on map.

What I want to do is have a custom animation to my marker when he appear. Not moove the camera.

Comment: @TomJouin Hey buddy, I know you may have already solved it but if not  It is a very simple thing. everything lies in your code just do it step by step like looking into it when you are showing all the required markers on the screen to the user and starting your animation after it. Thank you

Comment: No it isn't a very simple thing.